# IFS: How to move a label on a file

Tags: tfs

Can someone tell me whether it's possible to move a lable inside a file history?

I'm having following situation:

- our sources have a label applied
- one file has got a fix and was checked-in after being labeled

Now I'd like to specify the new version of the file as the labeled one. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved by my own:

- Select target file
- Context menu --> View History
- In the View History window change to tab Labels
- Context menu --> Edit label
- In the new window navigate to the target file
- Context menu --> Change Labeled Version --> Workspace Version

This causes the workspace version to become labeled version

Comment: Great! And don't forget to save the Label window to commit your label changes.

Answer (score 0):

you can also solve this easily by using tf.exe:

```
tf.exe unlabel "my label" $/project/branch/file.txt
tf.exe label "my label" $/project/branch/file.txt
```